# ASP.NET "HTTPS" WebService

Tags: javascript, web-services, https

1) When I create a Webservice (.asmx) in Asp.Net, its default is HTTP, but I need it in HTTPS..
How to do this?

2) And is it possible then to access to the methods on this webservice with "JAVASCRIPT" - even if the Server is HTTPS?

Hope u guys can help me..

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would adjust IIS on the webserver to make the service HTTPS. You would add a certificate to the website in IIS and check the "Requires Secure Channel (SSL)" check box (this will then redirect people attempting to use HTTP to HTTPS.

You should then be able to make AJAX calls from JavaScript by ensuring that you call your service with an https:// prefix, rather than a http:// prefix.

Comment: the AJAX Calls from JavaScript doesn't work, because u cannot bypass the server, cause its HTTPS, I don't know why, but for example the XMLHttpRequest, there isn't anything u can do, HTTP works fine..

Comment: You need to abide by the Same Origin Policy - but you should be able to do this. i.e. if you are calling mysite.com/service.asmx from mysite.com/mypage.aspx it will work. You should be on the same DOMAIN, using the same PORT and using the same PROTOCOL.